# A question about equivalence condition of measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am stucking following propoistion in ($\Leftarrow$ ) direction.

> Prop. Let (X, $\mathcal{A}$), (Y, $\mathcal{B}$) be m'ble space and $\mathcal{B}$= $\sigma$ ($\mathcal{G}$), $\mathcal{G}$ $\in$ $\mathcal{P}$(Y), then the function f : X $\to$ Y is m'ble iff $f^{-1}$ (G) $\in$  $\mathcal{A}$, for every G $\in$ $\mathcal{G}$

Within the proof, (in order to check, ($\Leftarrow$ )), Define the function

$\mathcal{M}$:= { B $\subseteq$ Y :  $f^{-1}$ (G) $\in$  $\mathcal{A}$}

and it is easy to check    $\mathcal{M}$ is $\sigma$-algerbra and  $\mathcal{G}$   $\subseteq$ $\mathcal{M}$ . And, then the author checks $\sigma$ ($\mathcal{G}$)  $\subseteq$ $\mathcal{M}$.(If it is true, then obviously the proof would complete!) But, I don't understand why such set realtion holds.
Clearly, to check this,  pick A $\in$  $\sigma$ ($\mathcal{G}$). and (considering defintion of Borel  $\sigma$ -algebra), there are two cases exist :

> **Case 1)** A $\in$   $\mathcal{G}$($\subseteq$    $\sigma$
>   ($\mathcal{G}$))
>
> **Case 2)** A  $\in$  $\sigma$ ($\mathcal{G}$), but A $\notin$
>   $\mathcal{G}$

**Case 1)** is clearly, A  $\in$  $\mathcal{M}$ , however, in **Case 2)**, I don't know how to to get the result.

Comment: $\sigma(\mathcal{G})$ is, by definition, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the collection $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: You might have misread the problem.

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every set in your second case, you can find a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{G}$ that converge towards $A$.
Since you have shown that $\mathcal{M}$ is a sigma algebra, the pre-image of your sequence converging towards $A$ must also be in $\mathcal{M}$.

More formally: 

*By some lemma we know that we can find $A = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}G_n$ such that $G_n \in \mathcal{G}$. 
 
We know by assumption that $G_n \in \mathcal{M}$ and that $\mathcal{M}$ is a monotone class. Therefore, we have that $A = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}G_n \in \mathcal{M}$*

Comment: Which Lemma uses to find the set A = $\bigcup$  $G_n$ s.t   $G_n$  $\in$ $\mathcal{G}$  ?

Comment: That in a semi-Algebra generated by a set, you can write any element of your semi algebra as a finite union of elements of the generating set. And that any element of your algebra generated by your semi algebra can be written as a union of elements of your semi algebra. Just combine the two together to get the quick proof. You can find the proofs in most of the measure theory books. You can find a proof of my first statement in that video https://youtu.be/ZyiI3cARLT0